# This dynamic mask in flex4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to make a **dynamic mask** for a component, as depicted in the image bellow. These white circles will appear in different places. The black area will have the content, the white ones will be the transparent area (you can change the colors if you like).

No clue how to make this mask. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an app that uses a `BitmapImage` and it's `maskType` property to do this. Note that this technique only works with `BitmapImage` and other components that extend the Spark `GraphicElement` class.

The `GraphicElement` class defines a `maskType` property, which if set to `MaskType.LUMINOSITY` will do the opposite of "normal" masking. The areas in the masking object that have nothing drawn on them will reveal the underlying object. The areas in the masking object that have something drawn on them, will be transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
               backgroundColor="#0">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.core.MaskType;

            protected function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                var circles:Array = [
                    { x:25, y:25, radius:20 },
                    { x:100, y:100, radius:50 },
                    { x:200, y:50, radius:25 } ];

                var circleSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
                drawMaskCircles(circles, circleSprite.graphics);
                image.mask=circleSprite;
                image.maskType=MaskType.LUMINOSITY;
            }

            private function drawMaskCircles(circles:Array, g:Graphics):void
            {
                var l:int = circles.length;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0);
                for (var i:int=0; i<l; i++)
                {
                    var o:Object = circles[i];
                    g.drawCircle(o.x, o.y, o.radius);
                }
                g.endFill();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:BitmapImage id="image" source="klimt12-hp.jpg"/>

</s:Application>
```

If you'd like to use this approach with something that is not a `GraphicElement`, you'll have to take a snapshot of the component to capture it's bitmap data, then use that bitmap data with another `BitmapImage`. For example, lets say you wanted to mask a component that extends `VGroup`:

```
// assuming component that extends VGroup is a variable named: vgroup
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(vgroup.width, vgroup.height);
bmd.draw(vgroup);

// now we have captured a snapshot of the component
// show this to the user with a BitmapImage
var vgroupImage:BitmapImage=new BitmapImage();
vgroupImage.source = bmd;

// now apply the circleSprite (created in the code above) as the mask
vgroupImage.mask = circleSprite;
vgroupImage.maskType = MaskType.LUMINOSITY;
addElement(vgroupImage);
```

Comment: Actually I want the inverse: the circles delimits the transparent spots.